# $X,Y$ have the same distribution, then $X_n\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}X$, then $X_n\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}Y$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I am trying to understand convergence in law. My question is the following:

Given two random variables $X,Y$ with the same distribution,
is it correct to say that if a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in law to $X$, i.e.   $X_{n}\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}X$,  it also converges in law to $Y$ since it has the same distribution, i.e. $X_{n}\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}Y$ ?

Comment: Yes, because - as you wrote -  $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution (AKA law).

Comment: Things become clear if you interpret $X_{n}\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}X$ in words by: "the distribution of $X_n$ converges to the distribution of $X$". Then shows directly that it is legal to replace $X$ by $Y$ in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be the c.d.f. of both $X$ and $Y$, as they have the same distribution.

Let $F_n(x)$ be the c.d.f. of $X_n$, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

By definition, $X_{n}\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}X$ means that
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F_n(x) = F(x),$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (at which $F$ is continuous),
thus it becomes obvious that $X_{n}\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}Y$, as $F(x)$ is the c.d.f. of $Y$.